# PHP 5.4 in official repository

Tags: 12.04, php, official-repositories

When PHP will be updated to version 5.4.x in official repositories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP 5.4 has been in the official repositories since Ubuntu 12.10.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5

Comment: thanks, looks like it's true, it is time to upgrade to 12.10 :)